# Match a word from a link

Tags: regex

I'm trying to work with regex but I'm still not capable of. Asking for your help!

I have links like these:

- https://open.spotify.com/track/1Q07lxRM6aQJYtRFzQUtwu?si=LrEcPs3pSxaznY2GLH4V8Q
- https://open.spotify.com/album/7lyxArCeA4kkHRiYpnh8eA
- open.spotify.com/artist/1mBlZPMpRL8wT9aHBnBBph

I'd like to match the "artist" part in the last link. How can I do it? I thought about using slashes as "separator" than get the string from there but I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to extract the top directory name following the
domain name, how about:

```
import re
url = 'open.spotify.com/artist/1mBlZPMpRL8wT9aHBnBBph'
m = re.search(r'(?:https?://)?[^/]+/([^/]+)', url, re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
artist
```

Answer (score 0):

Below, I'm using `Python`.

It's just build a case insensitive regex that advance any chars (.) with +(1 or more chars) and than use a prefix that occurs always before artist link `artist/`, finally use `()s` to group. Inside ()s uses a class for letters and digits with  + suffix  (1 or more chars)

```
.+artist/([a-z1-9]+)
```

The replaced string it just

```
/1
```

The details vary a little bit according to the programming language adopted

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/vIKB0H/1):